# Multiplying the values of a key in a dictionary with the values of another key in the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Calculate the mean value of stock X returns. Display the output in the format "Mean return: ......". The numeric result has three decimal digits.

I tried taking the first step by trying to use for loops but ran into a block. Please help

```
"""Prediction of returns of Stock A and Stock B"""


    pred = {'scens': ['very pessimistic', 
                      'pessimistic', 
                      'baseline', 
                      'optimistic', 
                      'very optimistic'],                   # Scenarios of economic conditions 
            'probs': [0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.1],           # Scenario probabilities
            'stock X': [0.02, 0.07, 0.13, 0.15, 0.18],      # Returns of stock X in each scneario
            'stock Y': [0.06, 0.11, 0.14, 0.19, 0.21]}      # Returns of stock Y in each scenario
```

Comment: What you are asking for is not so clear?

Comment: Hi! I want to find out the mean returns of stock X in every scenario. The probability of each scenario is provided under 'probs' in the dictionary. The return for Stock x is given as well.

Comment: You mean multiply Stock X by each of probability. And get the sum of all and average of them?

Comment: yup that is what I meant

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems like you're looking for the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case). This can be calculated with a simple loop:

```
def expected_value_stock_x(probabilities: List[float], stocks: List[float]) -> float:
    total = 0
    for prob, stock in zip(probabilities, stocks):
        total += prob * stock
    return total
```

To format the result you can use `round(expected_value, 2)` to trim the result to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suit you?

```
"""Prediction of returns of Stock A and Stock B"""


pred = {'scens': ['very pessimistic',
                  'pessimistic',
                  'baseline',
                  'optimistic',
                  'very optimistic'],                   # Scenarios of economic conditions
        'probs': [0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.1],           # Scenario probabilities
        'stock X': [0.02, 0.07, 0.13, 0.15, 0.18],      # Returns of stock X in each scneario
        'stock Y': [0.06, 0.11, 0.14, 0.19, 0.21]}      # Returns of stock Y in each scenario

mean_return = 0
for index, returns in enumerate(pred['stock X']):
    mean_return += returns * pred['probs'][index]

print(round(mean_return, 2))
```

Results is `0.1115` which gets rounded to `0.11`

It should be easy to interpret. I used enumerate to have both the content and an index, so in case you want to access also other elements of the dictionary lists within the loop you can do so easily.